# PostGIS: How to find Nearest Neighbour but only within a direction range?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, direction, azimuth, knn

I am attempting to find the nearest neighbour to a geometry in a certain direction but am becoming stuck at the planning stage.
I understand the basic tools that I need but am failing to find anything that can limit on a direction range.

I am finding the nearest neighbour and getting the coordinates of the two closest points as so:

```
SELECT
    tb1.degrees
    --taking ST_StartPoint and ST_EndPoint to get my closest points
    ,ST_ShortestLine(
        tb1.geom
        ,(
            SELECT geom
            FROM table2 tb2
            ORDER BY tb1.geom <-> tb2.geom ASC
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
FROM table1 tb1;
```

But I do not want to find the nearest neighbour to the 'left' of this geometry, only right. When I say left, I actually mean `(degrees-90)` of the bearing for `tb1.geom`.

So how do I find the nearest neighbour but only in directions n°+180? Or, is this possible?

Comment: I am airing on drawing a line from centroid of geom 1 at n°+90 for a distance that I know will intersect some and then finding the nearest neighbour from the returned list but it feels wildly unhygienic.

Comment: So why don't you add filter by X coordinate of centroids coords of other geometries greater than the X coordinate of centroid of your base geom ?

Comment: I may be being stupid but the left and right is only relevant to the direction/bearing of the geometry.

Comment: Your geometry is in geodesic system like WGS84 ? So yes, my solution will work (I think) only with projected coordinate system.

Comment: add the azimuth to your query https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77353/how-to-calculate-the-azimuth-of-a-line-of-a-multilinestring-in-postgis

Comment: @J.Monticolo No I am in Cartesian. I do use things like st_project but transforming to web mercator short of doing the trig later on (when I have learnt how)

Comment: @Mapperz I am not sure how this will aid the question but I will

Comment: I calculate the bearing using Azimuth in tb1

Comment: @J.Monticolo The bearing may be 10 degrees, I need to know what is left (which in this case left will be 10-191 degrees). I may be going in the opposite direction so 190 degrees (which in this case left will be 190-10 degrees).

Comment: So, the only solution I saw is yours, to construct an oriented box to contains "right" geometries as a pre-filter before the nearest neighbour. Or draw a line, do a `ST_BUFFER` only on one side (see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) and add a filter to contains geometries.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thanks for the response. Buffer side wont work as I cannot let PG to decide what is left and right but the line may work. 
Centroid of polygon is going to potentially be too far "left" so I will draw the line from the centroid, interpolate when it intersects the exterior ring of the polygon and then draw a line from this point at the degree+90 bearing again. Then I can see what geometries this line intersects with and then get the closest. As I mentioned previously I feel like I need a shower, that the solution is not clean but perhaps as a first solution it will give something.

Comment: I am extremely lucky that the geometries I am trying to find are long travel network LineStrings so I KNOW that it will intersect with what I need. If this solution was required to find anything within the bearing range this solution would not work.  Perhaps at a known likley distance you could draw the line and buffer the new line left and right so not buffering at the line points as you mentioned? I have not been in this world a long time but it is a lot of fun, sadly, for every bit of fun it seems to create 2 bits of stress; perhaps I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you skip the part where it is **highly ambiguous** to determine a positional geometric predicate on anything but an infinite line, that check itself is nothing but a 2D [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). The issue here is that it has to be applied to geometric primitives, i.e. an actual two-vertex vector representation, of which a *LineString* may have plenty (each segment between two consecutive vertices).
In effect, for each closest *Point* candidate you'd need to find the closest *segment* on the given *LineString*, then check for the positional predicate between their vector representations.

This could potentially be implemented in the core math of, say, `ST_DWithin`, and maybe even the index lookup of the *(K)NN* operator `<->`, since somewhere in their algorithms they have to include these per-segment operations already.

But it isn't, it might never be due to ambiguity and lack of usefulness, and in SQL this is bound to be *somewhat* dirty and inefficient...

---

...**but not entirely useless - and rather surprisingly performant**; tailor yourself some handy functions, and use a classic *(K)NN* query

1. Create a set of functions to loop over a given *LineString* vertices, find the closest two-vertex segment to a given point, and check if it is left or right of it:

   ```
   -- Utility function; returns the cross product of three Points
   -- if cp < 0 the point is to the right, cp > 0 to the left, cp = 0 on the line
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _ST_DeterminantSign (
     IN  pt GEOMETRY(POINT),
     IN  v1 GEOMETRY(POINT),
     IN  v2 GEOMETRY(POINT),
     OUT FLOAT
   ) LANGUAGE SQL AS
     $BODY$
       SELECT ( ST_X($3)-ST_X($2) ) * ( ST_Y($1)-ST_Y($2) ) - ( ST_Y($3)-ST_Y($2) ) * ( ST_X($1)-ST_X($2) );
     $BODY$
   ;

   -- loop over line segments of a given LineString, find its closest segment to a given point and check if it is to the right
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_IsRightOf (
     IN  pt GEOMETRY(POINT),
     IN  ln GEOMETRY(LINESTRING),
     OUT BOOLEAN
   ) LANGUAGE SQL AS
     $BODY$
       SELECT _ST_DeterminantSign($1, ST_PointN($2, n), ST_PointN($2, n+1)) < 0
       FROM   GENERATE_SERIES(1, ST_NPoints($2)-1) AS n
       ORDER BY
              ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN($2, n), ST_PointN($2, n+1)) <-> $1
       LIMIT  1;
     $BODY$
   ;

   -- loop over line segments of a given LineString, find its closest segment to a given point and check if it is to the left
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_IsLeftOf (
     IN  pt GEOMETRY(POINT),
     IN  ln GEOMETRY(LINESTRING),
     OUT BOOLEAN
   ) LANGUAGE SQL AS
     $BODY$
       SELECT _ST_DeterminantSign($1, ST_PointN($2, n), ST_PointN($2, n+1)) > 0
       FROM   GENERATE_SERIES(1, ST_NPoints($2)-1) AS n
       ORDER BY
              ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN($2, n), ST_PointN($2, n+1)) <-> $1
       LIMIT  1;
     $BODY$
   ;
   ```

   These functions here **only work on LineString and Point geometries**!
2. Run

   ```
   SELECT t.id, t.geom
   FROM   <table1> AS t1
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT t2.id, t2.geom
     FROM   <table2> AS t2
     WHERE  ST_IsRightOf(ST_EndPoint(ST_ShortestLine(t1.geom, t2.geom)), t1.geom)
     ORDER BY
            t1.geom <-> t2.geom
     LIMIT  1
   ) AS t
   ;
   ```

   to get the `t2.id` & `t2.geom` that is the closest to the right of each line in `t1`.

The core operation is **fully index driven** (ordering by distance via `<->`) and the filter applied only on the *NN* index subset returned by the `<->` operation; the function execution time itself increases linearly with the amount of vertices in the given *LineString*.

---

**Related:**

- [Order matched geometries on line by distance in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390215/order-matched-geometries-on-line-by-distance-in-postgis/390226#390226)
- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Is the Geometry(4326) an alias for Geography datatype?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367366/is-the-geometry4326-an-alias-for-geography-datatype/367374#367374)

Comment: @Phish did you try this? While this has not attracted much positive resonance - or rather none at all you ungrateful lot ,) - I am *extremely* pleased with the performance of the directionally restricted KNN search using the functions - I am going to wrap this into a custom operator and put it into a GitHub Gist this weekend.

Comment: Make a long thin triangle from your origin centred on a radial. Find all shapes that interect the triangle. Take the closest one to the origin. Modify the angle of the triangle as a tolerance measure.